# How to determine whether the for loop exited with an exception or break from inside iterator

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

I'm trying to handle clean-up in my generator, but only if the loop body raised an exception, rather than exited with `break`:

```
def f():
  for v in [1,2,99,4]:
    try:
      yield v
    except GeneratorExit:
      # how to determine whether generator exited via an exception?
      print("generator exited")
      raise
```

However, I have not found a way to tell the difference between `break` and an `exception` from within the iterator.

I.e. the following code

```
for v in f():
  if v == 99:
    break
```

will output:

> ```
> generator exited
> ```

And this code

```
for v in f():
  if v == 99:
    raise Exception("boom")
```

will output:

> ```
>  generator exited
>  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  Exception: boom
> ```

So from the outside of the generator, the difference is observable, but I cannot find a way to observe this inside the body of the generator `f()`

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: So the difference is which value is generated.  IE: from the example the `value == 99`  Why/how do you expect the generator itself to recognize a difference here?

Comment: The difference is how the yielded-to body reacts to the value. I.e. my cleanup behavior needs to be different on whether the exit from the generator was intentional or exceptional

Comment: My intuition says that it's impossible. Your Exception gets caught and turned into a `GeneratorExit` which doesn't contain the properties (e.g. `e.args`) of the first exception. It seems like you'd need to modify the source code to save off the first exception's properties in the `GeneratorExit` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this helps?

```
def f():
    for v in [1,2,99,4]:
        try:
            if v == 99:
                raise Exception('Boom!')
            yield v
        except:
            print("generator exited")
        else:
            print("generator not exited")

for value in f():
    print(value)
```

======================================================================

Probably, I still don't get the problem. Anyway, here is my 2nd try:

```
import sys

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def f():
    a = input('Break, except, loop, or quit (b/e/l/q)? ' ).strip().lower()
    if a == 'q':
        sys.exit()
    if a == 'l':
        pass    # just the normal loop
    for v in [1, 2, 99, 4]:
        if a == 'b':
            break
        try:
            if a == 'e':
                raise MyException
            yield v
        except MyException:
            print('Inside Generator: MyException')
            return
    else:
        print('Inside Generator: loop terminated!')
        return
    print('Inside Generator: break')

for value in f():
    print(value)
```

Comment: The `v==99` was simply to illustrate the behavior inside the iterator. It has no idea what value might cause the loop body to throw an exception, but needs to different cleanup if the for loop exited intentionally or due to an error.

Comment: @Arne Claassen: Apologies! I seem to not understand your problem. My code was just an example. If you know the possible exceptions, you can catch and handle them in the _except_ part. Only if there is no exception, the _else_ part becomes active. That way you should be able to determine if the loop was normaly terminated or not.

Comment: That's the problem. The exception never makes it to the except around the yield. It is hidden by the GeneratorExit that the generator raises on loop exit